# Getting no response while using react-native-sqlite-storage ,

Tags: react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

I am trying to execute update query but in response getting nothing.

```js
const editData = async (no) => {
     try {
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
          'UPDATE brief_History set para' +
            no +
            '=?,where id=?',
          [value, 2],
          (tx, results) => {
            console.log('Results', results.rowsAffected);
            if (results.rowsAffected > 0) {
              Alert.alert('Record Updated Successfully...');
            } else Alert.alert('Error');
          },
        );
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, you need to verify if the Database was initialized in App.

Example using **Expo**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

const App = () => {
  const [InitializedDatabase, setInitializedDatabase] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let tableValues = { table: "User", column: "Username TEXT, Password TEXT" };
    createTable(tableValues).finally(() => setInitializedDatabase(true));
  }, []);

  if (!InitializedDatabase) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  return (
    <View />
  );
}

const createTable = (value) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      db.transaction((tx) =>
        tx.executeSql(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${value.table} (${value.column});`,
          [],

          (_, { rowsAffected, insertId }) => resolve(insertId),

          (_, error) => reject(error)
        )));
```